# How can i access google contacts of users through gmail ids

Tags: google-api, google-api-java-client

I am asking user to sign-in through google account on my webapp, i want to get the user google contacts, right now i am getting email and profile.

Comment: Welcome to SO! can you please first share what you have tried..?

Comment: Thanks! I have tried the login functionality till now. I am getting access token and basic profile info. Now in order to extract the contacts i passed scope but it seems not working as the scope field is not identified. I want to request both contact access and signin in one request

Comment: add google contacts scope when you request access.   and read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask